# Landscape frame when in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, orientation, cgrect

Is it possible to retrieve the frame a UIView will have in landscape mode, whilst the device/interface is in portrait mode? If so, how is this done?

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail...

Comment: I don't know how I could be more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrThys, you should know how your view should be, either in portrait or landscape mode. After that, you can define them as constants like this:

```
#define myViewPortrait CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768.0f,1024.0f)
#define myViewLandscape CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f,768.0f)
```

You could then use these values when your device changes orientation. :)

Comment: I think he wants to know how how a view behaves after rotation, for example when it has set its autoresizing masks etc.

Comment: Hummm, in that case i don't know.

Comment: it's just a guess, the OP didn't comment so far, but for 50 points of bounty I am not sure if it would be that simple.

Comment: @Nick i did not quite understood what the OP wanted, what you say makes sense, although.

Comment: Haha, this method should work I could indeed just define constants with the frame that is required. But because I didn't want to modify the contants every time I adjust the XIB I was wondering if there was a dynamic method to retrieve the values for the frame in portrait and in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You know the dimensions of the screen will just swap the width and height. But if the status bar is visible the usable area will be different (e.g. 320x460 in portrait versus 300x480 in landscape on an iPhone), and then if you're in a UINavigationController or the like you'll have to take its chrome into account, and then if your view isn't the top-level view of the view controller in the container view controller you have to take into account the various autoresizing masks and any custom layout code too.

Why do you even need this? You should in general just respond to the size you're given in UIViewController's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` or UIView's `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: I need this because I want to init the view for with the correct frame before the user is viewing landscape

Comment: @MrThys: You can't just do it when the user rotates the device? Pretty much your only option is to try it and see what the frame is, and then hard-code that in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a reliable way to do this. In one of my projects I've used `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`. Querying either `frame` or `bounds` property of the view returns inconsistent results depending on wether the view is covered by another view (there may be other disrupting cases as well). Maybe the situation is different inside the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method.

In my case, I ended up implementing my own method to find out the view bounds:

```
- (CGSize)currentViewSizeWithOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient
{
  CGSize size = self.currentView.bounds.size;
  CGSize result;

  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orient))
    result = CGSizeMake(fminf(size.width, size.height),
                        fmaxf(size.width, size.height));
  else
    result = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(size.width, size.height),
                        fminf(size.width, size.height));
  return result;
}
```

In your case, you could try to find out the view frame once it's been loaded from the Nib. Then, either deduce what the frame will be in landscape orientation or explicitly set the frame in the Interface Builder and duplicate it in the code for both orientations.